# MLE: Two parameter or three parameter Weibull?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, weibull-distribution

I would like to calculate the MLE estimates of the mean and variance of a Weibull distributional assumption, from a given sample. Now, there are two parameter and three parameter weibull distributions. How would I know, which one would be a better choice? I can see that a two parameter distribution in general can account more for dispersion although.

Comment: The three parameter will always be a 'better fit' to the data (in the sense, say, of having a higher likelihood), since it includes the two-parameter version as a special case. Which is 'better' in a more general sense depends on your criteria for 'betterness' and the particular data you have.